# Why does InMemoryContext save changes to a repo without calling "save changes"?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core

In the unit test below I create an repository object and save the changes using InMemoryContext.  I then
modify the object but do not save the changes.  When I request the object from the repository
it shows the modification I made to the object even though no changes were saved.

When I create a new InMemoryContext and query the same object I get the original without any changes.

Why does the InMemoryContext decide that the object I request from the repository is really from the object and not actually the repo?  Can it be set to not behave that way?

```
        public void EFMeditechItsOrdersRepository_ContextTest1()
        {
            var orderId = 0;
            using (var context = TestingUtils.GetInMemoryContext())
            {
                var order1 = new Orders
                {
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    Cancelled = false,
                    Procedure = "SOMEPOC"
                };

                var eFOrdersRepo1 = new EFOrderRepository(context);
                eFOrdersRepo1.Insert(order1);  //Save the changes
                orderId = order1.Id;

                order1.Procedure = "HUHUH";  //Update to the object but not saving the changes

                var order2A = eFOrdersRepo1.Get(orderId);
                Assert.IsTrue(order2A.Procedure == "HUHUH");  //Why does this have the change when not saved???
            }
            using (var context2 = TestingUtils.GetInMemoryContext())
            {
                var eFOrdersRepo2 = new EFOrderRepository(context2);
                var order2B = eFOrdersRepo2.Get(orderId);
                Assert.IsTrue(order2B.Procedure == "SOMEPOC");  //Correct content
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the implementation for `GetInMemoryContext`, in addition to what your `Insert` method does.  Keep in mind that Entity Framework will provide cached values for methods like `Get`, and will look in-memory before going to the database to retrieve it.  This is the way it was built, if you don't want to reuse the same entities in a unit-of-work, then create a new unit-of-work (context).

Comment: ```        public static FHSContext GetInMemoryContext()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FHSContext>()
           .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "EF_InMemory_Database")
           .Options;
            return new FHSContext(options);
        }```   This is the implementation of the context

Comment: ```        public virtual void Insert(T entity)
        {
            mContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            mContext.SaveChanges();
        }```

Comment: These are the InMemoryContext implementations and insert